# Array of different properties with the same id in an object - React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am traversing an object that has an array of objects inside a property and I must access the id of an object to check which colors of my objects have the same id and make an array of the different colors of the same id to display it in the frontend as a concatenated. I hope you can help me.

Here I leave the image of the object on which I am getting the ids and colors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKHQo.png)

The dm_id are the ones I need to be able to make the color_bom_header array with the same dm_id

Here is the code that makes this happen but it doesn't work right :(

```
this.state.stylesArray = this.props.location.state.stylesCombo.components.map((index, current) => {
        const col = this.state.stylesCombo.components && (this.state.stylesCombo.components[current].style_colors = index.color_bom_name)
        if(this.state.stylesCombo.components && this.state.stylesCombo.components[current].dm_id === index.dm_id){
          if(this.state.stylesCombo.components[current].dm_name === index.dm_name){
            this.state.colorStArray.push(col)
            this.state.cstarr = [...new Set(this.state.colorStArray)]
          }
        }else{
          this.state.stylesCombo.components && (this.state.stylesCombo.components[current].style_colors = current.color_bom_name)
        }
        this.state.stylesCombo.components && (this.state.stylesCombo.components[current].style_colors = this.state.cstarr)   
      })
```

i have also tried with this but im stuck

```
 this.state.stylesArray = this.props.location.state.stylesCombo.components.map((current, index) => {
        for (current.dm_id in this.props.location.state.stylesCombo && this.props.location.state.stylesCombo.components) {
          if(current.dm_id === index.dm_id){
            
          }else{
            
          }
        }
        this.state.stylesCombo.components && (this.state.stylesCombo.components[index].style_colors = this.state.colorStArray) 
      })
```

Comment: I advice to read about `map` method. Precisely what arguments it take. Also it's really bad style to assign anything to your state.

Comment: What is your expected output? You should add that to the question. And add the actual input data to the question too as code not an image. It helps us debug.

Comment: @PYTHONDEVELOPER999 is right. You should read about the `map` method and also you shouldn't assign directly to the state. What you can do is create an empty array and then push the modified objects inside that array and then set the state.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So the task is to make an array of elements with the same ID.
We need to somehow count how many elements of each ID are presented. We can do that with an object.

```js
const counter = {}

for (const el of arr) {
  // if counter has element with given ID, increase the counter, otherwise initialize to 1
  counter[el.id] = (counter[el.id] || 0) + 1; 
}
```

Then we find ID that have the max count

```js
const max = Object.entries(counter).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc.length === 0) return curr;
  const [currKey, currVal] = curr;
  const [maxKey, maxVal] = acc;
  return currVal > maxVal ? curr : acc
}, [])[0]
```

And then we filter our state

```js
state.filter(element => element.id === max);
// or if `element.id` is of type number
// you need to cast `max` to Number first
const newMax = Number(max);
state.filter(element => element.id === newMax);
```

I'm not sure I didn't overcomplicate the logic but that's the way I came up with.